# CORS Can't pass HTML Markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jsonp, cors

I am currently converting our project from JSONP to CORS.

We are passing html form  as JSON Result, in JSONP it works fine, but when I migrated it to CORS the mark up  tags like div, form, p, are removed.

As of now I return the html as Content, and it works.

Just want to know why when I pass it as JSON result the markup is corrupted or something.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to pass it as JSON data, I just need to de-serialize it